# Trying to apply a Theme to my app but the custom configuration is not taking effect

Tags: reactjs

The following is in my root **index.tsx** file:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h4: {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
});

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AppRoutes />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Nested in the App is **HomePage.tsx** which has the following:

```js
// adding sx={headingStyle} to the header works
// but relying on the Theme does not work.
// const headingStyle = { color: "red" };

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <Grid item>
        <Typography
          variant="h4"
          // sx={headingStyle}
          fontWeight="bold"
        >
          Home Page
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox.io example](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-worker-v0wlto?file=/src/index.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are from the legacy package `@mui/styles`.
Instead, import them from `@mui/material/styles`.

So the solution is to replace `createTheme` and `ThemeProvider` imports like this:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

Here's a fixed fork:
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-voice-145qe6